# ssh terminal keeps on disconnecting at random times

Tags: centos, ssh

My ssh terminal keeps on disconnecting at random times(there is no particular time interval it disconnects). I am pretty sure that it is not from the tcp keep alive time which has been configured correctly. 
While checking the /var/log/secure I can see the log entry as:

sshd[56384]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user XXXXX

We are using centos 7.

Comment: I am not sure if you are using PuTTY to connect to the SSH server. PuTTY has a good log. In PuTTY, you can select Logging > SSH packets and raw data. The PuTTY logs attempt to tell the story of both the request packet from the client to the server and the response packet from the server to the client. Also, the PuTTY log attempts to identify the type of SSH packet being transmitted. When I've had SSH issues, I like to look at both the PuTTY log and the /var/log/secure file. Then I can compare the client side log with the server side log, to get a better idea of the cause of the SSH issue.

Comment: To get logs with ssh traditionnal client you can use the -vv flag

Comment: we are using xshell for ssh connection. Everytime when it disconnects the log file in /var/log/secure is always the same as :                      sshd[56384]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user XXXXX